# substring after a space in hadoop

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to substring a field in hadoop (for example Aaron Smith). I want to extract right side of the string after space (like Smith). Can someone help me with this please? 
Thanks

Comment: What database are you using?  Hadoop is a parallel framework, not a database.

Comment: I am using SAS to access Hadoop environment. I use scan function in SAS which doesn’t work in Hadoop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that you are using Hive, you can use `split()`:

```
select split(name, ' ')[1] as second_part
```